# Error 4712 al hacer truncate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola tengo estas tablas en mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que necesito hacer TRUNCATE TABLE a la tabla de Empresa y posteriormente a la de Login pero cuando quiero hacer el primer TRUNCATE me sale el error 4712 ya se hace referencia a la llave foranea, pero ¿hay una manera de hacer el TRUNCATE sin necesidad de borrar los datos que tengo en la tabla TipoEmpresa?

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Elimina la relación entre Empresa y TipoEmpresa, e intenta nuevamente el truncate table. Puedes hacer el truncate de la tabla login primero?

Comment: Algo estás haciendo diferente a como dices. La tabla Empresa la puedes vaciar cuando quieras, las que no te dejará vaciar serán Login y TipoEmpresa, porque Empresa las utiliza con sus FK o claves ajenas. Pásanos el SQL y lo comprobamos

Comment: Si la(s) tabla(s) tienes restricciones de integridad referencial con respecto a una tabla que vas a truncar, tienes que borrar esas restricciones. Borrar las restricciones no borra los datos en las tablas que no vas a truncar, simplemente las libera de la restricción que tienen y que impide el truncado en la otra tabla.

Comment: Para mostrar cómo están constituidas las tablas, qué restricciones tienen, etc, puede ejecutar por cada tabla un comando como `EXEC sp_help Login`, cambiando en cada caso el nombre de la tabla. Sería información importante para ayudarte con esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar `TRUNCATE TABLE` la tabla en cuestión no debe estar referenciada por una llave foránea. No importa si la tabla Empresa está vacía, no podrás utilizar el `TRUNCATE` en Login porque sigue teniendo una relación con la tabla Empresa. Si quisieras usar `TRUNCATE` necesitarías eliminar esa llave foránea.

Esto sucede porque TRUNCATE no revisa las filas y por lo tanto tampoco va a revisar las llaves foráneas. TRUNCATE sólo limpia las páginas de datos usadas por la tabla.

Aquí dejo el ejemplo de como eliminar la llave foránea antes de usar el TRUNCATE y como crearla de nuevo. Es importante asegurarnos de que sea en un proceso controlado y no perdamos la integridad referencial.

```
CREATE TABLE Logins(
    IdLogin int CONSTRAINT PK_Logins PRIMARY KEY,
    Usuario sysname,
    Contrasena  varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Empresa(
    IdEmpresa int,
    IdLogin int CONSTRAINT FK_Empresa_Logins FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Logins,
    --...
);
GO
ALTER TABLE Empresa DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Empresa_Logins;
TRUNCATE TABLE Logins;
ALTER TABLE Empresa WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Empresa_Logins FOREIGN KEY( IdLogin) REFERENCES Logins ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Y habrá otra forma de poder vaciar la tabla o sería solo eliminando registro?

Comment: Se puede usar el `DELETE` o eliminar y recrear la llave foranea para poder realizar el `TRUNCATE`. Añadiré el ejemplo.